# Is there a windows utility to list the current stack trace of all running thread for a .NET process into a plain text file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, stack-trace, diagnostics

Some background:
We have a .NET service application running and we would like to be able to generate a 'stack-trace dump' text file where we can see the current running threads and their stack traces in a plain text files. First idea was to enumerate all running threads in the application and get their stack-traces and just print them out from within the application. However it seems that there is no supported way to do that (you can not enumerate threads within the application and you can not acquire stack-trace information even if you know the threads). Additionally the method would not work if the application would hang as we would not be able to signal it to create this 'text dump'.

Is there a utility (or a set of utilities that can be executed through a batch file) to generate a plain text file where I can see all stack traces of all threads running within a .NET application/process?
Of course it should be able to read the .pdb files and print real method names.

I've seen that there are utilities to attach to a process and generate a standard dump files but I have no idea how I would use that dump file to get a user-friendly stack-trace in a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

procdump -> cdbg (the command-line version of WinDbg).

You'll need to load the SOS extension to get information about .NET threads, of course. There's a lot of heavy lifting involved, so don't be surprised it isn't entirely easy - but SOS hides almost all of that from you. As soon as SOS is online, just run `!EEStack` and you're done :)

If you need more details, the `!CLRStack` command can give you even more (including method arguments and local variables - only the ones that weren't optimized away, and without names, but hey :)), but it has to be run manually for each of the threads. This can be done with `~*e!clrstack`.

You'll need to have the Windows SDK installed (for WinDbg+Cdbg), ProcDump is a free (and unsupported) utility. You'll need to take a full process dump - the minidump doesn't have enough information to let SOS do its job, so it might be practical to do the dump->translation right on your server.

It might take you a while to get your bearings - WinDbg is a kernel debugger after all, and it's designed with very kernel-colored glasses. It allows you to do almost anything, though. If you're feeling adventurous, you could even skip the Procdump step entirely and attach directly to your process, saving on valuable time :)

Comment: To extend on your answer a suitable command line would be `cdb.exe -p <PID> -c ".loadby sos clr; .prefer_dml 1; !eestack"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it out.